# Create a folder adding a record

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Working in QGIS I have a point layer with ad attribute "NAME".
Is there any way to automatically create a folder called "NAME" where putting the attachments?
Maybe I could use something like this ["How to check if a directory exists and create it if necessary?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary)
But how could I checking it directly from the active layer in QGIS?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "attachment"? And your attribute, is this a field called "NAME"?

Comment: Attachments are files (pdf, tif ...) that describe the point (Building). "NAME" is the code of building.

Comment: What storage format are you using? If the files are in a separate folder, that's not really an "attachment", since it's not actually attached.

Comment: Right. I used a wrong word. I mean all the documentation about the building.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using the following in the **Python Console** which:

- Reads all attributes in your "NAME" field
- Checks the parent directory to see if it contains directories with the same name as the attributes
- If a directory does not exist, it is created.

  ```
  import os

  layer = iface.activeLayer()
  idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('NAME')  
  path = "path/to/directory"

  for feat in layer.getFeatures():
      attrs = feat.attributes()
      if not os.path.exists(path + attrs[idx]):
          os.makedirs(path + attrs[idx])
  ```

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - Most welcome, glad it worked :)