# Create output folder for merge result of Model Builder on QGIS 3.10

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, python-script-tool

I have export my model builder to python's script and now i would like to save the result to an created folder. But the folder name is based on a layer entity. Example: I have 3 layers (city, store, population) as input which gives me 2 results. I would like to save these 2 shapes in 1 folder which will have the name of a city. If I take Washington, Boston and Detroit, and launch my algorithm, it will take me out (thanks to the iteration), 6 layers in all. So I would like my 2 layers created for Washington to be automatically placed in the Washington folder and the same for the other 2 cities.

I tried that but it doesn't work : [Create a folder adding a record](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224936/create-a-folder-adding-a-record)
I have an error of the type: iface.activeLayer(city): too many argument.
I don't understand where is the problem.

EDIT : Now I can get the algorithm to work. This one creates the files of the cities concerned (so 3 files). But I can't put the files in the folders that concern them ...

My code

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
import os

france_substation_source_rte = iface.activeLayer()
selected_features = france_substation_source_rte.selectedFeatures()
idx= france_substation_source_rte.fields().indexFromName('code_poste')
path = r"C:\Users\utilisateur\Documents\Maps_GIS\dataset\data_analysis\automation_results\_"
for feat in selected_features:
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    if not os.path.exists(path + attrs[idx]):
        os.makedirs(path + attrs[idx])
```